# How display the data from sqlite db while clicking perticular list in android listview?

Tags: android

Am working on android project. Its like filling form. And I can list number of forms in listview. I have done this. But While clicking the particular form from listview, it should open with filled data & img which is retrieved from db is not working.

Can anyone help me with sample code.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `OnItemClickListener` method of the listview, get the events and do whatever you want.

Check [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)